# How do I insert into a multiple choice lookup column data from an Excel table

Tags: excel, list, sharepoint, lookup, power-automate

I made this same question on the Power Users forums [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Can-t-insert-into-a-multiple-choice-lookup-column-data-from-an/m-p/2307454)

I've been following this video on [how to import Excel data into a SharePoint list](https://youtu.be/uEZI_b1Gs-k?t=940): https://youtu.be/uEZI_b1Gs-k?t=940

There is a column on my SharePoint list that is a lookup with multiple choices enabled. However, I ran into the following error when running the flow:

> The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Criar_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: The API operation does not allow writing a value for parameter 'item/Unidade[0]/Value'. This parameter is read only.

Here's how the flow is now:

[Button trigger and getting items from list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmu6H.png)

[clearing list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyFOb.png)

[getting entries from spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93LK4.png)

[getting users from company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tOBB.png)

[creating array of users and inserting all data into list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTmyd.png)

What can I do to fix this?